# "git log --first-parent" without excluding any initial commits

Tags: git

I have a commit graph like this, where `A` and `G` are initial commits (no parents), and `B` and `D` are merge commits (with `A` and `C` as their first parents):

```
        F
       / \
      /   \
  A--B--C--D--HEAD
    /
G--E
```

I want `git log --graph` to show me:

```
  A--B--C--D--HEAD
    /
G--E
```

Doing `git log --graph --first-parent` gives:

```
A--B--C--D--HEAD
```

but I want to include `G` and `E`, because `G` has no parents. So when it encounters merge commit `B`, I would like `git log --first-parent` to also follow the second parent (`E`) because it allows it to reach the initial commit `G`.

The the logic I am looking for is "`--first-parent`, but only if all initial commits that are reachable from a merge commit are reachable from its first parent".

Is there a way to achieve this with `git log` or `git rev-list`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to achieve what you want using built in options to `git log` or `git rev-list`.

In your diagram, `E` is the second parent of `B`, so it gets excluded by `--first-parent`.

---

The closest I can think of is to do it in two commands :

```
(git log --graph --first-parent B..HEAD; git log --graph B) | less
```

The connection between `B` and `C` wouldn't be drawn in the output, but this should give you the correct list of commits.

Comment: Thanks, of course this does produce the correct set of commits, but I am looking for a more general solution and not something that requires explicit mention of `B` as my real repo has many merge commits like `B` where not all reachable initial commits are reachable from the first parent.

Comment: ok, I don't know of a way to tell git "please draw the relationship graph for that list of commits only", and there is no way to describe the graph you want (if I understood correctly : all the root commits, + 1 straight path from each to your current HEAD). You would have to write an external script to do that.

Comment: FWIW : you can dump the list of parents of each commit using `git rev-list --format="%P"`, and parse the output